# How do I convert a ASCII hex string (ex. "6C" to "l") in javascipt?

Tags: javascript, string, char, hex, ascii

How do I convert an ASCII hex string into a character?

Examples:

```
6E - n
26 - &
45 - E
```

I have searched on the internet but only found answers for the decimal system, not the double-hex format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `parseInt()` and `String.fromCharCode()`:

```js
const hex2Char = hex => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex, 16));

console.log(hex2Char('6E'));
console.log(hex2Char('26'));
console.log(hex2Char('45'));
```